# How do tell whether is a service/daemon is managed by System V Init scripts or upstart?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I understand that Ubuntu derivatives support `System V`, which some consider the old method of starting services for a specifc runlevel and `upstart` however how do I tell whether a service or daemon is managed by scripts started by init or upstart. Do the commands `service --status-all` and `initctl list` convey these or is there a single command that would tell me so?

Answer (score 0):

When you run ps, one of the fields is ppid.  You can use that to track it to its parent (the pid will match the process's ppid). Just track it back recursively. (You could probably script it with ps and awk)

or if you prefer a graphical way

```
ps -ely --forest
```

or just see if it is in /etc/init.d/* or /etc/rc.d/*

```
grep <something> /etc/*.d/*
```

Comment: Thanks. That allows me to trace it back to the parent process or daemon however how do I tell whether that process was started by init scripts or Upstart?

Comment: Updated answer with a couple alternatives.  What does the `ps -ely --forest` output look like?

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't tell me whether it has been started by upstart or scripts in the etc/rc*.d folders.